# Hide Page section on Page load

Tags: javascript, css

I created a function to hide a section on my Page until the user clicks a button to unhide it. Now the button is working well. But on Page load, the section
is not hidden, and the button says "Show More" instead of "Show Less".

See this page to see the button and the section behavior on Page load-- https://treeremoval.ga/tree-service-ulmar/#ShowMore

You will notice that all the 2 sections holding 6 images each are loaded, and the button is still saying "Show More",

This is not the expected behavior: the expected behavior should be that the lower section with 6 images stays hidden on Page load, and the button should say "Show More"-- which after clicking it should then reveal the hidden section, and the button then says "Show Less".

Although, when the button is clicked after page load, it starts functioning well--of hiding and unhiding the section, with the button Text changing accordingly to "Show More" and "Show Less".

The problem is only at page load. How do I ensure that at Page load, the section stays hidden? And the button says "Show More" in order to open the hidden section?

Here's my HTML:

```
<button id="ShowMore" onclick="toggleBlock()">Show More</button>
```

And here's the JS:

```
    function toggleBlock() {
  var myBlock = document.getElementById("service-area2");

  var blockButton = document.getElementById("ShowMore");

  if (myBlock.hidden) {
    blockButton.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    myBlock.hidden = false;
  } else {
    blockButton.innerHTML = "Show More";
    myBlock.hidden = true;
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, would you mind create a [mre]?. I can not see your HTML script

Comment: Add the `hidden` attribute on the section in html instead of making it hidden using JS. Everything else should work fine after that.

Comment: There are 2 things. 

1) I needed to target the element by its CSS Display Property. So I rewrote the Code to do just that.  

(2)Someone gave me this JQuery Code(( jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    toggleBlock();
}); )), and asked me to add it after my function. She said it will help me tell the browser to call the function when the page has loaded.  I did that as well. And Boom, everything is working well now. 

But if I use the HTML hidden attribute, would I still need to set the CSS Display Property to None?

Thanks all for your help.